# Struggling with getting MS SQL remote access to work

Tags: remote-access, sql-server

I'm still trying to get a remote access to the MS SQL Server on one of my Windows machine.

I allowed the access on my Windows firewall as can be seen [here](http://imgur.com/a/1c247) and [here](http://imgur.com/a/5Gp7v). I also opened the port on CoMoDo FW as can be seen [here](http://imgur.com/a/C93y4).

But trying to access the machine from the Linux with `busybox telnet 192.168.1.4 1433` does not produce "Connected".

The server itself does configured to accept the remote connections.

What other settings I'm missing?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

```
C:\Users\Igor>netsh firewall add allowedprogram program="C:\Program Files\Micros
oft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" name="Microsoft SQL
Server 2012 Database Engine Access" profile=domain,private
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct sy
ntax.

add allowedprogram
      [ program = ] path
      [ name = ] name
      [ [ mode = ] ENABLE|DISABLE
        [ scope = ] ALL|SUBNET|CUSTOM
        [ addresses = ] addresses
        [ profile = ] CURRENT|DOMAIN|STANDARD|ALL ]

  Adds firewall allowed program configuration.

  Parameters:

  program - Program path and file name.

  name - Program name.

  mode - Program mode (optional).
      ENABLE  - Allow through firewall (default).
      DISABLE - Do not allow through firewall.

  scope - Program scope (optional).
      ALL    - Allow all traffic through firewall (default).
      SUBNET - Allow only local network (subnet) traffic through firewall.
      CUSTOM - Allow only specified traffic through firewall.

  addresses - Custom scope addresses (optional).
              This comma-separated scope can contain IPv4 addresses,
              IPv6 addresses, subnets, ranges, or the keyword LocalSubnet.

  profile - Configuration profile (optional).
      CURRENT  - Applies to the active profile.  Active profile can be domain,
                 standard (i.e. private), or public. (default).
      DOMAIN   - Applies to the domain profile.
      STANDARD - Applies to the standard (i.e. private) profile.
      ALL      - Applies to the domain and standard (i.e. private) profile.
                 Does not apply to the public profile.

  Remarks: 'scope' must be 'CUSTOM' to specify 'addresses'.
           `addresses' can not contain Unspecified or Loopback addresses.

  Examples:

      add allowedprogram C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe "My Application" ENABLE
      add allowedprogram C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe "My Application" ENABLE CUSTOM
          157.60.0.1,172.16.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0,
          12AB:0000:0000:CD30::/60,LocalSubnet
      add allowedprogram program=C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe name="My Application"
          mode=DISABLE
      add allowedprogram program=C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe name="My Application"
          mode=ENABLE scope=CUSTOM addresses=157.60.0.1,
          172.16.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0,
          12AB:0000:0000:CD30::/60,LocalSubnet

      IMPORTANT: "netsh firewall" is deprecated;
      use "netsh advfirewall firewall" instead.
      For more information on using "netsh advfirewall firewall" commands
      instead of "netsh firewall", see KB article 947709
      at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=121488 .
```

[/EDIT]

[EDIT2]

SQL Server listens on 1433 as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVKms.jpg)

[/EDIT2]

Comment: . . . . This one too `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow SSMS Database Engine connections inbound on TCP 1433" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1433 profile=domain,private`... If you need PUBLIC then change `profile=domain,private` to be `profile=domain,private,public` as well for both commands

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, check my edit for the results running the first command. I'm running Win 8.1 with SQL Server 2012 Express.

Comment: Here you go, use this for the SQLServer.exe FW rule... just plug in the values for the valid path to the EXE file on this server/PC though... also ensure that the TCP port number is valid for the other command I wrote above too... `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Database Engine Access" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Sqlservr.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private`

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, that command finished successfully. And SQL Server does listen on 1433 as can be seen in the image from edit-2. Still trying "busybox telnet 192.168.1.4 1433" gives "can't connect to remote host: Connection refused". Any idea?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, the machine where the server is - 192.168.1.4, the client is Linux box - 192.168.1.2. Now how do I completely disable Win FW? And should I disable CoMoDo as well?

Comment: Bingo, I think you want to open **UDP port 1434** for the SQLBrowser communication... Try that when you get a chance or open the Windows OS FW for **sqlbrowser.exe** as you did for **SQLServer.exe** above with valid path, etc. I'll add an answer with this detail if any of this helps by the way.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, It looks like Windows FW is the culprit. Whether with or without CoMoDo I am getting "Connection closed by the foreign host". I can probably live without Win FW, since I have CoMoDo. Am I right?

Comment: That's your call since I'm not familiar with your infrastructure\exposure but that'd strip away one level of protection regardless. You are running SQL Server 2008, correct? Did you try adding the sqlbrowser.exe or the UDP port 1434 in the Windows FW since you at least now know that's the cuplrit it should just be a matter of what it's blocking and needs opened up.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT,   No, I'm running 2012 Express. I didn't try opening UDP yet, but everybody recommends keeping only 1 FW active. My setup is just a home environment.

Comment: That should suffice well then if you have no security concern otherwise. If the two FWs are on the same one Windows machine then that probably is overkill for sure at the OS level.

Comment: Igor - let me know what you did to get this working and if you think I should add an answer that you feel would be worthy or acceptance. I could add some detail about disabling the FW and rules to open up the access via Windows FW, and state optionally depending on your setup and security risks you could pick one or the other.